# Trouble with a join statement in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have two data files that I'm working with. One contains a list of words with some additional information about those words and the other one contains word pairs (where words are listed by their word IDs from the first table) and their frequencies.

Lexicon file (sample output)

```
('wID', 'w1', 'w1cs', 'L1', 'c1')
('-----', '-----', '-----', '-----', '-----')
(1, ',', ',', ',', 'y')
(2, '.', '.', '.', 'y')
(3, 'the', 'the', 'the', 'at')
(4, 'and', 'and', 'and', 'cc')
(5, 'of', 'of', 'of', 'io')
```

Bigram file (sample output)

```
('freq', 'w1', 'w2')
(4, 22097, 161)
(1, 98664, 1320)
(1, 426515, 1345)
(1, 483675, 747)
(19, 63, 15496)
(2, 3011, 7944)
(1, 27985, 27778)
```

I created two tables using SQLite and uploaded the data from the files above.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('bigrams.db')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')
```

Lexicon table

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE lex
            (wID INT PRIMARY KEY, w1 TEXT, w1cs TEXT, L1 TEXT, c1 TEXT)''')

#I removed this index as per CL.'s suggestion
#c.execute('''DROP INDEX IF EXISTS lex_index''') 
#c.execute('''CREATE INDEX lex_index ON lex (wID, w1, c1)''')

#and added this one
c.execute('''CREATE INDEX lex_w1_index ON lex (w1)''')
```

Insert data into the lexicon table

```
#I replaced this code
# with open('/Users/.../lexicon.txt', "rb") as lex_file:
#    for line in lex_file:
#        currentRow = line.split('\t')
#        try:
#            data = [currentRow[0], currentRow[1], currentRow[2], currentRow[3], str(currentRow[4].strip('\r\n'))]
#           c.executemany ('insert or replace into lex values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (data,))
#        except IndexError:
#            pass   


#with the one that Julian wrote

blocksize = 100000

with open('/Users/.../lexicon.txt', "rb") as lex_file:
    data = []
    line_counter = 0
    for line in lex_file:
        data.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
        line_counter += 1
        if line_counter % blocksize == 0:
            try:
                c.executemany ('insert or replace into lex values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', data)
                conn.commit()
            except IndexError:
                block_start = line_counter - blocksize + 1
                print 'Lex error lines {}-{}'.format(block_start, line_counter)
            finally:
                data = []
```

Bigram table

```
#I replaced this code to create table x2 
#c.execute('''CREATE TABLE x2
#             (freq INT, w1 INT, w2 INT, FOREIGN KEY(w1) REFERENCES lex(wID), FOREIGN KEY(w2) REFERENCES lex(wID))''')

#with the code that Julian suggested
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE x2
             (freq INT, w1 INT, w2 INT,
              FOREIGN KEY(w1) REFERENCES lex(wID),
              FOREIGN KEY(w2) REFERENCES lex(wID),
              PRIMARY KEY(w1, w2) )''')
```

Insert data into the bigram table

```
#Replaced this code
#with open('/Users/.../x2.txt', "rb") as x2_file:
#    for line in x2_file:
#        currentRow = line.split('\t')
#        try:
#            data = [str(currentRow[0].replace('\x00','').replace('\xff\xfe','')), str(currentRow[1].replace('\x00','')), str(currentRow[2].replace('\x00','').strip('\r\n'))]
#           c.executemany('insert or replace into x2 values (?, ?, ?)', (data,))
#        except IndexError:
#            pass

#with this one suggested by Julian 
with open('/Users/.../x2.txt', "rb") as x2_file:
    data = []
    line_counter = 0
    for line in x2_file:
        data.append(line.strip().replace('\x00','').replace('\xff\xfe','').split('\t'))
        line_counter += 1
        if line_counter % blocksize == 0:
            try:
                c.executemany('insert or replace into x2 values (?, ?, ?)', data)
                conn.commit()
            except IndexError:
                block_start = line_counter - blocksize + 1
                print 'x2 error lines {}-{}'.format(block_start, line_counter)
            finally:
                data = []

conn.close()
```

---

I want to be able to check if a given word pair exists in the data -- for example "like new"

When I specify the first word only, the program works just fine.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT lex1.w1, lex2.w1 from x2 
                INNER JOIN lex as lex1 ON lex1.wID=x2.w1
                INNER JOIN lex as lex2 ON lex2.wID=x2.w2
                WHERE lex1.w1= “like” ’’’)
```

But when I want to search for a pair of words, the code is painfully slow.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT lex1.w1, lex2.w1 from x2 
                    INNER JOIN lex as lex1 ON lex1.wID=x2.w1
                    INNER JOIN lex as lex2 ON lex2.wID=x2.w2
                    WHERE lex1.w1=“like” AND lex2.w1= “new” ''')
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use a cross-product join? `SELECT lex1.w1, lex2.w1 from x2, lex as lex1, lex as lex2 WHERE lex1.wID=x2.w1 AND lex2.wID=x2.w2 AND lex1.w1="like" AND lex2.w1="new"`

Comment: Also, you should use `EXPLAIN <query>` to see the execution plan of your query. That will hopefully show you where any inefficiencies lie and allow you to structure the query in a different way.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: Thank you. I tried the cross-product join, but it's as slow as the inner join. When I use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN with the join statement, I get this: (0, 0, 'TABLE x2')
(1, 1, 'TABLE lex AS lex1 WITH INDEX sqlite_autoindex_lex_1')
(2, 2, 'TABLE lex AS lex2 WITH INDEX sqlite_autoindex_lex_1').

Comment: This appears to work better in more recent SQLite versions.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: No, I'm still stuck. I'm not sure how to interpret the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output. I wasn't able to figure out how to improve the syntax of the select statement either.

Comment: @user3854605 well hopefully a bounty will bring some more expert eyes onto this question. I'm pretty curious myself since it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: Thanks for placing a bounty on my question! Hope there's somebody out there who has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your x2 table like this.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE x2
             (freq INT, w1 INT, w2 INT,
              FOREIGN KEY(w1) REFERENCES lex(wID),
              FOREIGN KEY(w2) REFERENCES lex(wID),
              PRIMARY KEY(w1, w2) )''')
```

Apart from being semantically correct, this creates a permanent index that will speed up your queries considerably. Without specifying that the pair of (w1, w2) is the primary key of the table, that index has to be *temporarily re-created* every time you run that query, which is a costly operation.

---

Code like the following can be used to re-define a table without needing to re-import everything.

```
c.execute('''
    create table x2_new (
        freq INT, w1 INT, w2 INT,
        FOREIGN KEY(w1) REFERENCES lex(wID),
        FOREIGN KEY(w2) REFERENCES lex(wID),
        PRIMARY KEY(w1, w2) )
''')
c.execute('insert into x2_new select * from x2')
c.execute('drop table x2')
c.execute('alter table x2_new rename to x2')
conn.commit()
```

---

The following code should speed up insertion.

```
blocksize = 100000

with open('/Users/.../lexicon.txt', "rb") as lex_file:
    data = []
    line_counter = 0
    for line in lex_file:
        data.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
        line_counter += 1
        if line_counter % blocksize == 0:
            try:
                c.executemany ('insert or replace into lex values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', data)
                conn.commit()
            except IndexError:
                block_start = line_counter - blocksize + 1
                print 'Lex error lines {}-{}'.format(block_start, line_counter)
                conn.rollback()
            finally:
                data = []

with open('/Users/.../x2.txt', "rb") as x2_file:
    data = []
    line_counter = 0
    for line in x2_file:
        data.append(line.strip().replace('\x00','').replace('\xff\xfe','').split('\t'))
        line_counter += 1
        if line_counter % blocksize == 0:
            try:
                c.executemany('insert or replace into x2 values (?, ?, ?)', data)
                conn.commit()
            except IndexError:
                block_start = line_counter - blocksize + 1
                print 'x2 error lines {}-{}'.format(block_start, line_counter)
                conn.rollback()
            finally:
                data = []
```

Comment: I tried creating the x2 table with a primary key on the (w1, w2) pair as you suggested but the code has been running since yesterday and the database with the lex and x2 tables is still not ready. The size of the lexicon file is 203.3MB and the bigram file is 1.34GB. Is there anything else I can do when working with files that are this big?

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do? Re-define the schema and fill the database from scratch? In that case your bottleneck may be in your Python code that inserts the data. Especially if you insert and commit your data one row at a time, that tends to be invariably slow. Perhaps you can try inserting your data 10000 rows at a time. I can offer more options, but it depends on your specific problem.

Comment: Yes I tried to rebuild the database from scratch. I'll edit my question and add the code for inserting the data.

Comment: If you still have your old database around, you may also create the new definition of `x2` under a different temporary name, e.g. `x2_new`, and then execute the SQL commands `insert into x2_new select * from x2; drop table x2; alter table x2_new rename to x2`. In general to speed things up, you may also run `vacuum; analyze` once in a while (doing that very often is not useful though).

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes you suggested and added them to the code above.
I needed to remove 'c.commit()' because it was giving me an AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'.

Comment: Thanks to your code for inserting data into tables, I discovered some errors in the database 
'c.executemany ('insert or replace  into lex values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', data)
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 4 supplied.' I fixed the entries that were giving me an error and added an index on ‘w1’ as CL. suggested.  
I don’t know if I’m missing something but I tried to recreate the table (I lost the old one) and it's still taking too long.

Comment: I was assuming that `c` was a connection. You do want to commit at the point where I wrote `c.commit()`, because otherwise everything you insert will keep lingering in your memory, which might explain why your computer becomes very slow (or at least I assume it becomes slow to respond). You should have a connection object somewhere; assuming it is called `com`, insert `com.commit()` at the samen position where I wrote `c.commit()`.

Comment: I understand now. I used 'c' to create cursor. Sorry I didn't have that piece of code in my original question. I added the commit part and I'll run it again.

Comment: The code seems to be working now, and the database journal is being updated periodically, but it's been over 24hrs since I ran the code and it still hasn't finished processing. Is it possible that I still have some inefficiency in the code or is the processing time expected to be long when dealing with files that are over 1.5GB?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a mere 1.5GB to take more than 24 hours, but I have never tried that many data on a SQLite file, so I might be wrong. The only other issue I can think of is that my `except` clauses should end with a `conn.rollback()` (I will edit that in my answer). If you have many index errors in your files, I think that might slow things down or perhaps even compromise your database, depending on the specifics of `executemany`.

Comment: I added conn.rollback() and ran the code again. It's been 9hrs now and it's still running. I might be wrong but I don't think there are any more errors in the database. I run my old code without the 'except IndexError: pass' part yesterday and it didn't produce any more errors.

Comment: I'm giving the bounty to this answer due to Julian continually coming back to help the OP in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. I hope my answer has been useful after all; let's see whether your query has sped up when the importing is done!

Comment: It took a few days to create the tables but the select statement to retrieve word pairs works fast now! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

The EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN shows that the database scanned the `x2` table first, and then looked up the corresponding `lex` rows for each `x2` row, checking if the words match.
The `lex` lookups were done with a temporary index, but doing this lookup twice for each row in `x2` still made the entire query slow.

The query would be fast if the database could look up the IDs of the two words first, and the search for a row with these two IDs in `x2`.
This requires some new indexes.
(The `lex_index` index would be useful only for lookups beginning on the on the `wID` column (and such lookups could already use the primary key index).)

You need to create an index that allows searching for `w1`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX lex_w1_index ON lex(w1);
```

To look up any `x2` row(s) containing the two word IDs, you need some index with these two columns in the leftmost position:

```sql
CREATE INDEX x2_w1_w2_index ON x2(w1, w2);
```

Alternatively, make these two columns the primary index (see Julian's answer).

---

To force the database to do the word ID lookups first, you could move them into subqueries:

```sql
SELECT freq
FROM x2
WHERE w1 = (SELECT wID FROM lex WHERE w1 = 'like')
  AND w2 = (SELECT wID FROM lex WHERE w1 = 'new')
```

However, this should not be necessary; with the new indexes, the optimizer should be able to find the optimial query plan automatically. (But you can still use this query if you think it's more readable.)

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense to remove the lex index since I already have a primary key on wID. I'll try the code to force the word ID lookups once the database is completed. It seems that it's being built just fine now but it's not done yet.

Answer (score 2):

If finding the rows for one of the words is indeed fast, you could create a temporary table from the results of that, then search again in that table. So for example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x2_temp;
CREATE TABLE x2_temp AS
    SELECT lex.*, x2.w2 from x2 
        INNER JOIN lex ON lex.wID=x2.w1
        WHERE lex.w1 = 'like';

SELECT x2_temp.*, lex.* from x2_temp
    INNER JOIN lex ON lex.wID=x2_temp.w2
    WHERE lex.w1 = 'new';
```

You can also combine the two, without using a temporary table (not sure if that helps):

```
SELECT x.*, lex.* FROM 
    (SELECT lex.*, x2.w2 FROM x2 
        INNER JOIN lex ON lex.wID=x2.w1
        WHERE lex.w1 = 'like') AS x
    INNER JOIN lex ON lex.wID=x.w2
    WHERE lex.w1 = 'new';
```

(These execute in sqlite3, but I don't have the data, and I didn't take the time to create test data; but it should be correct.)